# Marriages in Caracas Venezuela 1969

Tags: marriage-records, venezuela, 1960s

I was married in Caracas in 1968 or 1969. How I can obtain these records from that time? I live in the USA now and need documentation for USCIS to process my Citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

See the article in the FamilySearch Research Wiki [Venezuela Genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Venezuela_Genealogy) to begin.

On the right-hand side of the page, under the section Record Types, choose either [Civil Registration](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Venezuela_Civil_Registration) or [Church Records](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Venezuela_Church_Records) to learn more. The articles link to collections about marriages which are online, or you can start with a FamilySearch Catalog place search for [Venezuela](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=402&query=%2Bplace%3AVenezuela). Check all jurisdictions by opening the panel **Places Within Venezuela** at the top of the catalog results and choosing the appropriate district.

I am not familiar with the current requirements that USCIS might have for documentation.  Since this is for your citizenship process and not simply for family history research, you may find it more convenient and efficient to hire a professional genealogist. The Association for Professional Genealogists has a directory of members. See the [Search Tips](https://www.apgen.org/cpages/directory-search-tips) page for advice on how to search the directory.

Other Resources:

- Family Search Research Wiki: [Venezuela Online Genealogy Records](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Venezuela_Online_Genealogy_Records)
- World Genweb: [Venezuela](https://www.worldgenweb.net/venezuela/)
- Cyndi's List: [Central and South America](https://www.cyndislist.com/central-and-south-america/)